# I want to create a horizontal menus in ASP.NET project

Tags: asp.net

How to create menu lists in ASP.NET. Can any one help me to build that?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the ASP.NET's [`MenuControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ecs0x9w5%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) with **`Orientation="Horizontal"`**

```
<asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal">
  <Items>
    <asp:MenuItem Text="File" Value="File">
      <asp:MenuItem Text="New" Value="New"></asp:MenuItem>
      <asp:MenuItem Text="Open" Value="Open"></asp:MenuItem>
    </asp:MenuItem>
    <asp:MenuItem Text="Edit" Value="Edit">
      <asp:MenuItem Text="Copy" Value="Copy"></asp:MenuItem>
      <asp:MenuItem Text="Paste" Value="Paste"></asp:MenuItem>
    </asp:MenuItem>
    <asp:MenuItem Text="View" Value="View">
      <asp:MenuItem Text="Normal" Value="Normal"></asp:MenuItem>
      <asp:MenuItem Text="Preview" Value="Preview"></asp:MenuItem>
    </asp:MenuItem>
  </Items>
</asp:Menu>
```

Here's a good [**overview**](http://aspalliance.com/1916_ASPNET_Horizontal_Menu_Control.all) from ASP alliance

Answer (score 0):

There are two options that you can create menus.

1. Dynamic Menus
   2.Static Menus.

Static menus you can get from any website.

And Dynamic Menus you have to create which will populated from database.

If you want you can check out this post. 
[Dynamic Menus in Asp.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6733918/asp-net-3-5-c-best-way-to-create-and-display-dynamic-menu-with-submenus/10320299)