# ASP.NET 3.5 C#: Best way to create and display dynamic menu with submenus

Tags: c#, asp.net

I usually just create a datatable with one repeater and have all this html in my codebehind.  I have not found an easy method for adding a submenu dynamically. Does anyone have a way to do this better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Render as a nested list of lists (`<li></li>` elements in a `<ul></ul>`). Use a jQuery menu plugin to convert to  a dynamic menu.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, I would use a server control for a menu, that would add copies of itself for submenus, making it dynamically generated. However, consider caching it, as it is not quick to generate.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a xslt File and Get the records from the database dynamically.

[Download the Full Source Code](http://getcode.in/2012/04/create-dynamic-asp-net-menus-from-database/)

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head id="Head1" runat="server">
     <title>DataBase Driven Menu</title>

     </head>
     <body>
     <form id="form1" runat="server">
     <div id="myslidemenu" class="jqueryslidemenu">
     <asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" StaticEnableDefaultPopOutImage="False"
     Orientation="Horizontal" StaticSubMenuIndent="10px" BackColor="#FFFBD6"
     DynamicHorizontalOffset="2" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="0.8em"
     ForeColor="#990000">
     <DataBindings>
     <asp:MenuItemBinding DataMember="MenuItem" NavigateUrlField="NavigateUrl" TextField="Text"
     ToolTipField="ToolTip" />
     </DataBindings>
     <DynamicHoverStyle BackColor="#990000" ForeColor="White" />
     <DynamicMenuItemStyle HorizontalPadding="5px" VerticalPadding="2px" />
     <DynamicMenuStyle BackColor="#FFFBD6" />
     <DynamicSelectedStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" />
     <StaticHoverStyle BackColor="#990000" ForeColor="White" />
     <StaticMenuItemStyle HorizontalPadding="5px" VerticalPadding="2px" />
     <StaticSelectedStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" />
     </asp:Menu>

     </div>
     </form>
    </body>
    </html>

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Xml;
using System.Data;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
 if (!IsPostBack)
 {
 DataSet ds = new DataSet();
 XmlDataSource xmlDataSource = new XmlDataSource();
 xmlDataSource.ID = "xmlDataSource";
 xmlDataSource.EnableCaching = false;

string connStr = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=G:\Admin\WebSite28\App_Data\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
 using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
 {
 string sql = "Select ID, Text,NavigateUrl,ParentID from Menu";
 SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
 da.Fill(ds);
 da.Dispose();
 }

&nbsp;

ds.DataSetName = "Menus";
 ds.Tables[0].TableName = "Menu";
 DataRelation relation = new DataRelation("ParentChild",
 ds.Tables["Menu"].Columns["ID"],
 ds.Tables["Menu"].Columns["ParentID"],
 true);

relation.Nested = true;
 ds.Relations.Add(relation);

xmlDataSource.Data = ds.GetXml();

//Reformat the xmldatasource from the dataset to fit menu into xml format
 xmlDataSource.TransformFile = Server.MapPath("~/TransformXSLT.xsl");

//assigning the path to start read all MenuItem under MenuItems
 xmlDataSource.XPath = "MenuItems/MenuItem";

//Finally, bind the source to the Menu1 control
 Menu1.DataSource = xmlDataSource;
 Menu1.DataBind();
 }

}
}
```